# RabbitMQ vs NodeJS Addon for C++ Application Integration

Tags: javascript, c++, node.js, rabbitmq

I have an application developed in C++ with which I would like to interact from a NodeJS server.  My question is:  Will there be a very substantial loss of performance insofar as data sent to/from the C++ binary utilizing RabbitMQ?

As a case example: Assume I am sending 10kb of data to the C++ binary every millisecond, and receiving 10kb of data in my NodeJS server every millisecond back from the C++ binary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there will be no performance loss. All data is transferred over AMQP, and how AMQP "datapackets" are formed is no issue (there are all the libs listed on rmq website, probably some that aren't as well).

Now something a bit subjective if I may - when you add c++ to any mix, there can only be a performance gain :)